# KRDC maps both 'alt' and 'meta' keys to 'meta' when connecting to a MAC vnc host

Tags: keyboard-layout, mac, vnc

I am on a kubuntu machine with a mac keyboard connecting via krdc / vnc to a mac OS host.

i have a problem with the krdc key mapping

- the meta key maps to meta key on the mac [good]
- the alt key also maps to the meta key on the mac [bad]

essentially i lose the ability to use the alt-key when using this particular setup. any way i can change the key mapping for krdc and/or this krdc session?

Comment: http://ryan.gulix.cl/dw/desarrollo/informatica/contenidos/xkeycaps
(wiki is on Spanish or Italian, but can be easily translated via Google Translate) Also, you can use console utilities : https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/xmodmap https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/X_keyboard_extension https://rlog.rgtti.com/2014/05/01/how-to-modify-a-keyboard-layout-in-linux/ https://www.charvolant.org/doug/xkb/html/xkb.html

Comment: my local alt / meta keys do not need  remapping, just when using krdc connected to a osX host

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `xkeycaps`? You may want to remap that alt key if it is being sent as the meta key.

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/xkeycaps.1.html

```
sudo apt-get install xkeycaps
```

Comment: That looks like a way to modify the keybindings in ubuntu, im looking to modify the keybindings in a specific vnc connection (krdc). But, wasnt aware of this program, will definitely make use of it for adding some programming symbols to my keyboard!

Comment: It would be great if you could add some instructions about how `xkeycaps` could help the OP!